# Force ending of paragraph in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, octopress

Is there any way to signify that a code block ends a paragraph?

There's a related prior org-mode issue where in some cases you don't want to start a new paragraph.

I ran into this issue with my blog at http://www.railsonmaui.com. I worked around this issue by editing the octopress scss file _syntax.scss, as I described here: http://www.railsonmaui.com/blog/2013/04/27/octopress-setup-with-github-and-org-mode/

Comment: What version of Org-Mode are you running?

Comment: Org-mode version 7.9.2+ (7.9.2+-GNU-Emacs-24-3 (commit 488eea) @ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org/)
Is this optimal? (running on Mac OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory a new paragraph in Org-Mode is defined by a blank line (Two carriage returns) between elements.

I'm not certain how well this was respected prior to the inclusion of `org-element.el` and `ox.el`.  You'll need version 8.0 for that (It might be in 7.9.3 but definitely is in 8.0).

However there is no exporter/blogging engine for Octopress build on the new framework (although there is a Markdown exporter), so I'm not certian if that will help you.

I would suggested trying to add extra blank lines/ensure there are no blank lines as required to enforce paragraph breaks.

---

To upgrade to a newer version of Org-mode you can follow the instructions in the [Org FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#Keeping-current).

1. Download the release `zip` or `tarball` : [here](http://orgmode.org/index.html#sec-3)
2. Use git to keep up to date: `git clone git://www.orgmode.org/org-mode.git`
3. Use `ELPA` to install a more recent version.

Comment: What's the best way to upgrade org-mode given that it's included in emacs rather than in the packages.

Comment: Sweet. I used ELPA. Just needed to restart after putting in the package. Also, I did not see the org-plus-contrib package listed.